# how to upgrade cassandra from 0.8 to 2.1.8

Tags: cassandra

now we have an Cassandra database version 0.8, we want to upgrade this to 2.1.8, from the document looks like we need to upgrade 1.2.9 first, could anyone help us give us some suggestions how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consult the [DataStax Upgrade Guide](http://docs.datastax.com/en//upgrade/doc/upgrade/cassandra/upgradeCassandra_g.html) and make sure to read the upgrade sections of all versions starting with 0.8 in the [NEWS.txt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/cassandra/cassandra-2.1.8/NEWS.txt) file.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to follow the upgrade guide now, but I faced some problem, now I have upgrade the database from 0.8 to 1.0.9, and when I trying upgrade the cassandra from 1.0.9 to 1.2.9 the partitioner is different, 1.0.9 use the RandomPartitioner and 1.2.9 default use the Murmur3Partitioner. How could I upgrade my database's partitioner?

Comment: It's not a good idea to change the partitioner for an existing cluster, as it won't be able to find your data afterwards. You should change it back to `RandomPartitioner` in `cassandra.yaml` after the upgrade.

Comment: thank you ~~ @Stefan Podkowinski, now I have upgraded successfully, still use the RandomPartitioner